# Comparing info for WISE and GALEX

Tags: telescope, space-telescope, magnitude, wavelength

I'm trying to compile a table showing the wavelengths and flux at m=0 for WISE, Spitzer and GALEX, but I can't find the right data for GALEX. Here's what I have so far:

```
        Band    Wavelength      F_0
                micrometers    Jansky
        ------------------------------
        FUV     0.152   
        NUV     0.227   
        U       0.365           1810
        B       0.445           4260
        V       0.551           3640
        R       0.658           3080
        I       0.806           2550
        J       1.220           1600
        H       1.630           1080
        K       2.190           670
        W1      3.4             309.54
        W2      4.6             171.787
        SPIT8   8               64.13
        W3      12              37.674
        W4      22              8.363
```

I got most of the info from [here](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/~dfabricant/huchra/ay145/mags.html). The information I found for GALEX on page 687 of [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5321/ac845601d0882b5e7d32f6dfdd4d60acb1f0.pdf) gives m_0 for NUV and FUV, but no F_0. How can I change m_0 to F_0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GALEX magnitudes](https://galex.stsci.edu/GR6/?page=faq#ANSWER2) use the [AB system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AB_magnitude), which means that $F_{0} \approx 3631$ janskys for both NUV and FUV, *by definition*.